# Fragments with recyclerviews taking long time to load

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my app, there is a viewpager which contains four different tabs. In each tab, there are five different fragments loading inside nested ScrollView, and each fragment loads a recyclerview. Everything loads but the problem is that when there is a large amount of data attached to recyclerviews, data takes long time to load. Sometimes, it takes even more than 10 seconds to load and it is quite irritating when someone has to wait for that long time. Please help me to solve this issue. In each tab, the same fragment which is provided below loads but with different data.

My code seems like the following.

```
public class MyViewPagerFragment extends Fragment implements 
View.OnClickListener {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            BatsmanHelper.addNotBattedBatsmanFromPlayingXI(context, team, team.getBatsmans_list(), match);

            FragmentOneWithRecyclerView fragment1 = new FragmentOneWithRecyclerView();
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
            // put some data in the bundle
recyclerView.setArguments(bundle1);
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment1_container, 
fragment1).addToBackStack(null
            );

            FragmentTwoWithRecyclerView fragment2 = new 
FragmentTwoWithRecyclerView();
      bundle1 = new Bundle();
            // put some data in the bundle
fragment2.setArguments(bundle1);
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment2_container, 
fragment2).addToBackStack(null
            );

FragmentThreeWithRecyclerView fragment3 = new 
FragmentThreeWithRecyclerView();
            bundle1 = new Bundle();
            // put some data in the bundle
fragment3.setArguments(bundle1);
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment3_container, 
fragment3).addToBackStack(null
            );


FragmentFourWithRecyclerView fragment4 = new FragmentFourWithRecyclerView();
            bundle1 = new Bundle();
            // put some data in the bundle
fragment4.setArguments(bundle1);
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment4_container, 
fragment4).addToBackStack(null
            );

            transaction.commit();

    return view;
}


}
```

Comment: The delay is a combination of a lot of factors such as the item layout inside the Recyclerview, the data that you are reading from somewhere to display inside the Recyclerview items. Combining that with multiple fragments and multiple tab is bound to take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is two issues :

1. the items in your recyclerView may take long time to load . (then you must optimize your adapter)
2. instead of using bundle , in which fragment build a method like this :

   ```
   public void setCustomData(Object data){

      this.data = data ;

   }
   ```

then just use `fragment.setCustomData(yourStuffs);`

Comment: But how to optimize adapter?

Comment: @ShehryarZaheer i dont know hows you adapter , but you can simply build all your view instances and controll them Only in the viewHolder class , and use onBind method only when you need update elements . as another thing if you are using image in list items  load images by an imageLoader like picasso .